# Postgresql port troubles

Tags: postgresql, debian, port

Installed postgresql on Debian 8. But it's not listening port. Need help.

```
# service postgresql status:
 Active: active (exited)

# sudo netstat -pant | grep postgres:
nothing

#sudo netstat -pant | grep 5432:
nothing
```

Comment: Maybe it's configured to run on a different port?

Comment: Maybe init.d attempted to start it, but postgres failed to start (because initdb hasn't been run or PG_DATA is not set correctly)

Comment: resolved.
It's was wrong pga_hba.conf